# What is the difference between using Python's Invoke vs a regular shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, pyinvoke

I've been reading a bit about Python's [PyInvoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/), and my interest was piqued. Essentially, I want to have allow users to utilize a software without needing to go through the tedious task of installing all dependencies. I was think of making a simple shell script that would do that when I stumbled upon PyInvoke. So... I am wondering if this is useful or not and what is the difference compared to just having a shell script within the directory?

Comment: You write your tasks in python i/o bash.